# PATCH request in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

For each of my logged in users, they have a row in a 'settings' table, which gives me more information about the individual settings the user needs when using my web app.

Okay so, In Laravel 5.6, I want the user to be able to update the settings.  However it might not be there if they are first logged in, I dont know if a PATCH request checks for the row before it attempts to update it?

Either way, Here is my settings model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use \App\User;

class Settings extends Model
{
    protected $connection = "mysql";
    protected $table = "settings";

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

Okay, so that makes sense to me. In my `settings.blade.php` I have the form pointing to /settings:

```
<form action="/settings" method="POST">
@csrf
```

Then in my `SettingsController.php` I have the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use \App\Settings;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index() {
        return view('settings');
    }

    public function patch() {

        Settings::patch(request([
            'font',
            'updates',
            'font-size',
            'hide-intro',
            'hide-commentary',
            'night-mode'
        ]));

    }
}
```

And finally my /routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/settings','SettingsController@index');
Route::patch('/settings', 'SettingsController@patch');
```

Okay so that to me should work, I know theres no validation but I can put that in later.  However I get the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

What can I do to fix this? Am I going about this all the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `pass` method `verb`. Add this in your form

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

Comment: Ooh okay, so now I get: `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::patch does not exist.`

Comment: Because that method doesn't exist on your `Settings` model.

Comment: @N.B. looking back at other projects I didnt think it needs to exist - It's a patch request, so much the same as `model->create()` it's built in?

Comment: Model doesn't have patch method instead use `Settings::updateOrCreate(....` as @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz suggested. for more information read : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates

Comment: @FahimUddin, Okay i've put that method in however I'm not getting any database changes.  Does it know which user  to update?

Comment: @Chud37 just write ``user_id` => $id` as the first element of the array to specify the user if you have column in your table to make relation between users and settings, thus it will know that this user should be updated or if it does not match then it will know that it needs to create a new record.

Comment: @Chud37 what is requirement here, what does your function do?? could you please explain

Comment: @Chud37  there's no logic in your statement. An HTTP `PATCH` request has no logical link to Eloquent's inbuilt function whatsoever. If you think that because there exists a `get()` method or a `delete` method, that there must exist a `patch()` or `post()` or `put()` then that's incorrect.

Comment: @N.B. Yeah, I really don't know what I am talking about.  Which is why I posted the question.  I stated above that I really dont know if even this is the correct way to go about what I want to.  In started PHP/SQL, I would simply check if a row exists for that user in the settings table, if it does, run an `UPDATE .... WHERE user_id = :userID;`, How can I do that in Laravel???

Comment: `DB::table('your_table')->where('id', 1)->update(['column' => 'value']);`. No need to deal with Eloquent, you can do it this way. Of course, change the values, I think it's pretty clear what's what, right?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following `method_field()` inside form

```
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```